# Unit test to check order of React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component called Page that contains 2 components a and b like below -

```
<div>
<div id="component-a"></div>
<div id="component-b"></div>
</div>
```

In my unit test, I want to confirm the components' ordering i.e. if "component-a" comes before "component-b".

Going through [shallow wrapper docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html), I felt I will have to iterate through all children till I find component-a. If I find component-b before that, then false else true.

Is there a better way to achieve the above? It would have been great if I could have a method that gives me child position of a given element.

For now I am only checking the presence of "component-a" which is not enough (like below).

```
const wrapper = mount(<Page {...props} />);
expect(wrapper.find('.component-a')).toHaveLength(1);
```

Comment: does it work with pure css ? find(".component-a + .component-b")

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but maybe you can do a snapshot test? This can make sure you and your teammates won't accidentally change the order of this component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Page {...props} />);
const elementsOrder = [];

for(let order = 0; order < wrapper.children().length; order++) {
    elementsOrder.push(wrapper.children().at(order).prop('id'));
}

expect(elementsOrder.indexOf('component-a')).toBeLessThan(elementsOrder.indexOf('component-b'));
```

Comment: I don't know the position of the components here. I said just 2 for simplifying the example.

Comment: If you notice, I mentioned that iterating through all children till I find component-a is something one can always do. I am still marking your answer accepted as there seems nothing better shallow wrapper provide